# Removing the empty space left when overlaying text into an img,(html,css)

Tags: css, html

Im new into html,css and im trying to do a menu for a mobile App which consist in some images next to each other aligned vertically, I want to overlay some text to this images. 
For example, imagine a main menu of an Sports info related App, it contains 5 background images, football image, basketball image, golf image...an each image has the text at the bottom of them.

To approach this, I made the following html code:

```
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div id="cabecera">

        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-opciones">
        <div class="opcion-menu">
            <img src="../img/tarta.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="./web/Acercade.html"></a>
            <h2><span>Sobre txorierri y Erandio</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="opcion-menu">
            <img src="../img/tarta.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="./web/LugaresDeInt.html"></a>
            <h2><span>Lugares de interes</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="opcion-menu">
            <img src="../img/tarta.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="./web/DondeComer.html"></a>
            <h2><span>Dónde comer</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="opcion-menu">
            <img src="../img/tarta.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="./web/DondeDormir.html"></a>
            <h2><span>Dónde dormir</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="opcion-menu">
            <img src="../img/fronton.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="./web/TiempoLibre.html"></a>
            <h2><span>Tiempo libre</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This way im getting the image,then the text,then another image,then another text... so by css I repositioned the text to overlay each image. The problem is that now I get and empty space where the text before was, and I want the images to be next to each other. What is the best way to get rid of that empty space? notice that since this is for a mobile App I want to avoid working with pixels on css, and try to do all % related.

Comment: Being able to see your CSS too would be really helpful. A jsfiddle example would be even more ideal :)

Comment: please take a look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and recreate your problem so we can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but I think you can clean up your html and achieve what your looking for. You could wrap each list item in an the  and get the same effect. For Example:

```
<div class="opcion-menu">
            <img src="../img/tarta.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="./web/Acercade.html"></a>
            <h2><span>Sobre txorierri y Erandio</span></h2>
</div>
```

change to:

```
<div class="opcion-menu">
<a href="./web/Acercade.html"><img src="../img/tarta.jpg" alt=""><span>Sobre txorierri y Erandio</span></a>
</div>
```

Then you set the  to position:relative and the  to position:absolute to take it out of the flow of the document. This will also eliminate that white space and you can position it or hide it in relation to your image using left:-9999; and opacity:0;

Hope that helps you somewhat.